# Подключение самосозданного модуля Python

Tags: python

1. Нужно создать модуль в котором написать  3 функции, каждая из которых принимает список. Первая функция – получение максимального значения, вторая – получение минимального значения, третья – получение суммы всех элементов.
   Я написал но он не работает подскажите почему пожалуйста:

```
def getmax(arr):
    max = arr[1]
    for n in arr:
        if n > max:
            max = n
            return max


def getmin(arr):
    min = arr[0]
    for n in arr:
        if n < min:
            min = n
    return min


def summa(arr):
    a = sum(arr)
    return a
```

2. Нужно написать мини программу импортировать туда созданный модуль. Так же он должен по нажатию цифры выполнять следующие функции из модуля 1 - Сложение; 2 - Вычитание ; 3 - Умножение; 4 - Деление; 0 - Выход из программы и выводить результат.
   Хоть и модуль не работает я все равно написал программу она тоже не работает. помогите исправить ошибки:

```
import spiski
while True:
    print('1 - Максимальное значение списка; 2 - Минимальное значение списка ; 3 - Сумма чисел списка ;  0 - Выход из программы')
    code = input('Введите команду:  ')
    if code == '0':
        exit(0)
    arr = [
        i for i in range(
            int(input('Введите знчение списка 1(Начальное): ')),
            int(input('Введите знчение списка  2(Конечное): ')))]
    if code == '1':
        r = spiski.getmax(arr)
    elif code == '2':
        r = spiski.getmin(arr)
    elif code == '3':
        r = spiski.summa(arr)
    print('Результат', '=', r)
```

Comment: Вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас в `getmax` проблема с табуляцией - `return` в цикле после проверки сразу идет. А основном скрипте логических ошибок нет, в чем конкретнее он не работал? Также вопрос: Вам надо был свои функции `max`, `min` и `sum` написать? Я задаю этот вопрос Вам, потому что в первых двух случаях Вы делает свою реализацию, а в последнем используете встроенную функцию `sum`.

Из того, что я понял:

Файл `Main.py`:

```py
import MyModule

while True:
    code = input(
        '1 - Максимальное значение списка\n'
        '2 - Минимальное значение списка\n'
        '3 - Сумма чисел списка\n'
        '0 - Выход из программы\n'
        'Введите команду: '
    )
    if code == '0':
        break
    
    start = int(input('Введите начальное значение списка: '))
    end = int(input('Введите конечное значение списка: '))
    
    array = list(range(start, end)) # Список: [Start; End)
    if code == '1':
        result = MyModule.get_max(array)
    elif code == '2':
        result = MyModule.get_min(array)
    elif code == '3':
        result = MyModule.get_sum(array)
    print(f'Результат = {result}')
```

Файл `MyModule.py`:

```py
def get_max(array):
    result = array[0]
    for element in array:
        if element > result:
            result = element
    return result

def get_min(array):
    result = array[0]
    for element in array:
        if element < result:
            result = element
    return result

def get_sum(array):
    result = 0
    for element in array:
        result += element
    return result
```

P.S. Используйте встроенные функции `max`, `min`, `sum` в реальном коде, т.к. они написаны на C, поэтому работают быстрее - [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578896/python-built-in-sum-function-vs-for-loop-performance)

Comment: Непонятно только, зачем вы в двух местах использовали конструкцию `for ... else`, при том, что в этих циклах нет `break`.

Comment: Ну и названия файлов по-хорошему должны быть такие же говорящие, как названия переменных. Что за `A` и `B`? )

Comment: @CrazyElf Подправил! =) 1) Это я так просто пишу, чтоб видно было `return`. 2) Нууу... Для меня было понятно, но теперь я всё подправил!

Comment: Просто сами пишете, что у автора вопроса нет единообразия в функциях - и тут же делаете своё не единообразие в функциях, это было смешно )

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну да, есть такое) Спасибо за серьезную критику!